Ecovent smart vent not integrating with Zigbee hub
I'm not sure if this is the best forum to post this question. Please feel free to suggest/repost to appropriate community if needed.
I just bought Ecovent Smart Wall Vent ENEV412C. It didn't come with an instruction, can't find anywhere on the Internet either (asked the distributor's customer support but they don't have one either). I don't even see this product is zigbee capable, but I do see Connectivity: 915 MHz encrypted network, which I assume zigbee in the US (at least another seller's website (discounthomeautomation.com) mentions Zigbee).
Among other things, the problem I'm running into is that I haven't been able to integrate the device into an existing Zigbee network.
I'm seeing a green light blinking on a seemingly computer module in the device (see this  video on my Google Photos. Sorry SE seems not allowing to embed a video), but starting the integration on my Zigbee hub doesn't seem to find the device.
I guess Ecovent was acquired by Keen*1. This page (keenhome.io) shows a brief instruction for wireless integration, which didn't help me.
My Zigbee hub is the one comes with Home Assistant. Home Assistant ver at the time of writing: 2024.5.3.
Any help is appreciated.
*1...I got that impression by reading through this page (keenhome.io).


HomeAssistant is software. You need a network-connected ZigBee radio (coordinator) to talk to ZigBee devices. What do you have? 2. If the device doesn’t explicitly say it’s ZigBee, why would you assume it is? The manufacturer’s brochure says they sell a hub that offers ZigBee connectivity in addition to their “encrypted 915MHz”, which implies the devices do not speak ZigBee directly.


@nobody Thanks. I updated OP to clarify in response to your comment, but I now agree with your finding and opinion. Posted an answer. If you can post another answer then I'll mark it as an answer (assuming this thread won't attract much more new info as the product seems discontinued).

As the finding @nobody mentioned in the comment, the manufacturer's brochure for their smart hub connects encrypted 915 MHz and allows Zigbee connection, which implies the vent device must connect to smart hub via their proprietary wireless, not Zigbee.

Just to reiterate: you will not be talking to even a 100% native ZigBee device with HomeAssistant (on a computer) alone. You will require a “ZigBee coordinator”, which is a device containing a ZigBee radio transceiver and a network interface (Ethernet or WiFi) that HomeAssistant can talk to.

Not all ZigBee devices use 2.4GHz and the protocol they speak on that frequency is not WiFi or Bluetooth. WiFi and Bluetooth radios cannot talk to ZigBee devices.
